# How to solve $x^2+xy+y^2=(\frac{x+y}{3}-1)^3$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

How would I solve $x^2+xy+y^2=(\frac{x+y}{3}-1)^3$? I have found the solution $y=12-x$ but I am not sure how to prove its the only solution, any help?

Comment: Set. $ x+y-3=t\iff x=?$

Comment: `I have found the solution y=12−x` That's not a solution, try $x=12, y=0$ for example.